# how I use flash message in yii2?

Tags: php

how I add flash message to my site using related controller please explain step by step i'm new to the php.

I use yii2 framework to build the site and i need to print flash message in the index page using create controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently the question is too broad, but here is basic usage:

**1)** You can set in controller like that:

```
\Yii::$app->session->setFlash('flashMessage', 'Hello world!');
```

**2)** Then you can display it in view like so:

```
echo \Yii::$app->session->getFlash('flashMessage');
```

Optionally you can check the existence with:

```
\Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('flashMessage');
```

**Official docs:**

- [Session](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html)
- [setFlash()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#setFlash%28%29-detail)
- [hasFlash()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#hasFlash%28%29-detail)
- [getFlash()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#getFlash%28%29-detail)

There are actually more methods for working with flashes, you can see it in official docs.

Also advanced template provides useful widget [Alert](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/widgets/Alert.php) that integrated with Boostrap 3:

```
\Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'This is the error message');

...

echo Alert::widget();
```

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding of working with flash messages, go through @ [http://www.yiiframework.com](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/). By following this method, you can done printing flash messages in your web page.